# jQuery DataTable rows order

Tags: jquery, datatable

```
dTable = $('#periods_grid').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": false,
    "bPaginate" : false,
    "bDestroy" : true,
    "bFilter": false,
     aaData : myArray
});
```

Why rows order is messed up ? I want rows order to be the same like they are in the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See here:

[Is there a way to disable initial sorting for jquery DataTables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964388/is-there-a-way-to-disable-initial-sorting-for-jquery-datables)

Simply set `"aaSorting" : []`

Comment: ty, i was trying aaSorting : undefined