# grails sort by date not working

Tags: sorting, grails, java.util.date

I have domain object named Roll and on the list page i want to show the user all the Roll objects iterating through a list, sorted by entry date.

Here is the code i am using

```
[rollList: Roll.findAll(sort:"rollDate"){userid==uid}]
```

rollDate is a field inside the Roll object with data type java.util.Date

Any suggestion on why the output is not sorted by rollDate. When i iterate through the rollList on the gsp page it is not sorted.

Also, on the Roll domain object i have even put this code, but it's still not sorting.

```
static mapping = { 
    sort "rollDate"
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: It works as expected from the `findAll` query without the aforementioned entry in mapping block. How does the gsp look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why aren't you using the `dynamic finders`?

```
Roll.findAllByUserid( uid, [ sort:"rollDate", order: 'desc'] )
```

should work.

The `findAll( Map, Closure )` method appeared not a long time ago, perhaps it was not tested well...

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use order in your query as well, then add order to it

```
[rollList: Roll.findAll(sort:"rollDate", order: 'desc'){userid==uid}]
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying both the solutions mentioned it still didn't work. So i thought something might be wrong on the front end.
While researching more i found that since i was using jquery data tables it used to re order the sorting. The solutions i found was here

[jQuery DataTable rows order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778872/jquery-datatable-rows-order)

So both the answers above are correct. The issue was actually with jquery data tables.