# Disable Ordering Columns after initialization (init complete) in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I would disable order possibility to user after datatables is draw.
I have a datatable, and I would order a data and remove possibility, for an user, to order data manually.
How can I do it?

I used below code:

```
table = $('#tbl-1').DataTable({
            "info": false,
            "searching": true,
            "paging": false,
            "iDisplayLength": 25,
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "Tutti"]],
            "language": {"url": "include/it_IT.txt"},
            "order": [[1,"desc"]],              
            //"ordering": false,
            //"orderFixed": {"pre": [ 1, "desc" ]},                             
             "fnInitComplete": function(oSettings, json) {
                    //alert( 'DataTables has finished its initialisation.' );
                    this.fnFilter("<?php echo $_POST['search'];?>");                        
                  },
            }).on('init.dt', function (e, settings, data) {
                wrappa(); //after custom function
            });
```

Comment: [http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/7377/disable-all-sorting-after-init](http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/7377/disable-all-sorting-after-init)

Comment: I just see it but dosen't work on my site

Comment: **Addressing some potential confusion**. If you're looking to disable auto-sorting of your (e.g. server-side sorted) table after datatables init, but keep the sorting functionality enabled for intentional use, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4964423). If you want to disable the sorting completely, see below for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

old post but still not handled by dt api. Removing the events won't work if wanting to temporarily disable sorting. Instead use jquery to add and later remove a class onto each th, and in this class specify "pointer-events: none".

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that the API does not have a way to do this, I would suggest the following approach

Declare your table at first

```
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
```

Re-Initialize your dataTable with to disable ordering

```
//Destroy your table before
table.destroy();
$('#myTable').dataTable( {
  "ordering": false
} );
```

reference:
https://datatables.net/reference/option/ordering

Comment: this isn't correct because i need to ordering first time, and only after ordering i must disable..

Comment: if you set `ordering : false` on the column OP wants to prevent the user to be able to sort on, he will loose his own ordering, eg `"order": [[1,"desc"]]`, as well.

Comment: This will disable the ordering completely