# Is there a way to restore sorting for jquery DataTables to none?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, datatable, datatables

Im using [jQuery DataTables](https://datatables.net) plugin. With this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964388/is-there-a-way-to-disable-initial-sorting-for-jquery-datatables) I know how to initialize the table without any particular order (ordering com from server).

Now, I need to clear the table ordering. Using the [order method from API](https://datatables.net/reference/api/order()) I can apply order to the first column, i.e:

`api.order([0,0]);`

But doing this :

`api.order([]);`

Get this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined`

How can restore the original "no order" state of the table?

Comment: You cannot do it this way, through the API. params for `order()` (or `fnSort()`) **must** be a valid column index and a valid sort type.

Comment: @davidkonrad so, no way to reload data from server without ordering?

Comment: ?? Where are you reloading data? Just saying that you cannot reset the ordering to none or "no order" by using `order()`. You can set the `ordering` with `order()`, but not _unset_ it.