# Jquery Data Tables sorting issue

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using [datatable](https://datatables.net/) to show my data in a table and my code is like this:

```
$('#data_table').DataTable(data);
```

Right now i want to apply the properties "order": [] to the data table.
I already tried below option but not working.

```
$('#data_table').DataTable( {
"order": [],
data:data,
} );
```

Comment: What is not working? what are the errors you are getting? Which version of datatables are you using? Could you explain your question a bit further?

Comment: I am using version DataTables 1.10.13 and the result showing No data available in table.

Comment: @SahanSerasinghe Here is the screenshot of the result i am getting.https://www.screencast.com/t/UevBAZrNwM2s  but when i am using  $('#data_table').DataTable(data);  the table is coming fine with data

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify which columns you need to apply ordering and what order(asc or desc)

```
"order": [[ 0, "asc" ]], where 0 is for first column
```

in case you need more its

```
"order": [[ 0, "asc" ],[1 , "asc"]]
```

Comment: I was looking to implement the following option.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964388/is-there-a-way-to-disable-initial-sorting-for-jquery-datatables