# Order by not working correct with Data-Table

Tags: c#, jquery, datatable

My code works good . The problem is when i apply Data-table to the result the order in which the result shows change . But when i remove data table the result ordered correctly

```
  <div class="box-body no-padding">
  <div>
    <table id="example2" class="table table-hover table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <% if (Request.QueryString["P"].ToString() == "S")
                                                   { %>
            <th>To</th>
            <%} else {%>
              <th>From</th>
              <%} %>
                <th></th>
                <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <%if (DtInbox.Rows.Count > 0)
                                              {
                                                  for (int i = 0; i < DtInbox.Rows.Count; i++)
                                                  {
                                            %>
          <tr>
            <%string x = DtInbox.Rows[i]["Mb_Idno"].ToString(); %>
              <%if (DtInbox.Rows[i]["AStatus"].ToString() == "New")
                                                  {%>
                <td class="mailbox-name">
                  <a href="Mailbox-read.aspx?Id=<%=DtInbox.Rows[i][4]%>&P=<%=Request.QueryString[" P "]%>">
                    <b><%=DtInbox.Rows[i]["SD_StudentName"]%></b></a>
                </td>
                <%}
                                                  else
                                                  {
                                                %>
                  <td class="mailbox-name">
                    <a href="Mailbox-read.aspx?Id=<%=DtInbox.Rows[i][4]%>&P=<%=Request.QueryString[" P "]%>">
                      <span style="font-weight: 500"><%=DtInbox.Rows[i]["SD_StudentName"]%></span></a>
                  </td>
                  <%
                                                  }
                                                %>
                    <td class="mailbox-subject"><b><%=DtInbox.Rows[i]["Subject"]%></b> &nbsp;-&nbsp;
                      <span style="font-style: italic"><%=DtInbox.Rows[i]["Message"]%></span>...</td>
                    <td class="mailbox-date" style="padding-right: 20px; font-weight: 400">
                      <%=Convert.ToDateTime(DtInbox.Rows[i]["Date"]).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")%>
                    </td>
          </tr>
          <%}
                                              } %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <!-- /.table -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.mail-box-messages -->
</div>
```

This is my query

```
select  SD_StudentName,substring(Subject,0,40) as Subject,substring(Message,0,50) as Message,Date,Mb_IdNo,OLM_Mailbox.SD_IdNo,Ad_Id,AStatus
            from    OLM_Mailbox inner join OS_StudentDetails on OLM_Mailbox.SD_IdNo=OS_StudentDetails.SD_IdNo
            where   Ad_Id=1 and (AStatus='New' or AStatus='Viewed') order by  Date desc , Mb_Idno desc
```

The result that i get to the **DtInbox** is in the correct order . but when it apply to ** jquery data table ** the order of the result changed . Please help me
My Jquery only contains

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/json2/0.1/json2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#example2").DataTable();
        });
    </script>
```

check the images
[Correct result without data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxtD4.png)

[Order changed when data table applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dgnc.png)

Comment: It seems as DataTables is performing an initial ordering which overwrites the ordering you specified. To disable this initial ordering, try the solution in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964388/is-there-a-way-to-disable-initial-sorting-for-jquery-datatables

Comment: @DanDumitru Thank you sir  Its works for me .. As a comment i saw in the link above **You have no idea how happy I am to see this answer!** is same for me thanks a lot