# Hide Sort Icons

Tags: asp.net, datatables, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 3.3.7 and datatables 1.5.2.  At present I have a table where I want the data to appear in order and I don't want it sortable by the user.  So I set all columns to be sort false by putting "orderable": false in all column defs.  This stops sorting, but the very first column the sort icon in the column remains.  What do I need to do to hide the sort icon in this first field?

Edit:  OK this is just getting downvoted.  What am I asking wrong in this question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964388/is-there-a-way-to-disable-initial-sorting-for-jquery-datatables)

Comment: My own googling did not turn up this thread, thank you so much! that has solved my problem and removed the sort icon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sytor's response above solved it.  This thread has the full explination: [Is there a way to disable initial sorting for jquery DataTables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964388/is-there-a-way-to-disable-initial-sorting-for-jquery-datatables)

I'm only replying here because I can't mark his response as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your program only shorting icon display but work perfectly.
The icons is defined as background : url(..) on the CSS classes. Disable them by :

```
.sorting, .sorting_asc, .sorting_desc {
    background : none;
}
```

Comment: I've seen this suggestion before but adding this to my CSS sheet doesn't seem to have the anticipated result, to stop the sort icon from appearing.  I have even tried using '!important" to prioritize it but is has also not solved it.