# Why does DataTables change the order of my rows when I call 'DataTable()' on an existing HTML table?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a very simple HTML table that renders in the order that I want it to without any call to 'DataTable()' in the '$document ready()'  function call.

## Old output

```
<table id="mytable" class="display">
    <thead>
         <tr>
             <th>Title</th>
             <th>Value</th>
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
         <tr>
             <td>Item1</td>
             <td>1</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Item2</td>
             <td>2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Item3</td>
             <td>3</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Item4</td>
             <td>4</td>
         </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

However, after calling 'DataTable()' the ordering is seemingly random.

## New output

```
<table id="mytable" class="display">
    <thead>
         <tr>
             <th>Title</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <th>Value</th>
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
         <tr>
             <td>Item4</td>
             <td>4</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Item3</td>
             <td>3</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Item1</td>
             <td>1</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>Item2</td>
             <td>2</td>
         </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

## DataTable call

```
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#mytable').DataTable({
                            "stripeClasses": [],
                            "pageLength": 25,
                            "rowReorder": {
                                    enable: false
                            }
                    });
            });
    </script>
```

Why does DataTables do this? Is there anyway I can preserve my ordering (1,2,3,4)? I've taken a look at the documentation options, specifically [Row ReOrder](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowReorder.enable), but to no avail.

I realize I *should* be calling DataTable with ajax and all that jazz, but that is a little beyond what I'd like to be doing right now. I'd just like to square this away first.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] so we can see exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Added the DataTable call. Anything else that would be helpful here?

Comment: Your table is badly formed.... you have no `tr` (rows) in the head and only `tr` .... no cells, `td` in the body. Do you want 2 colums of 4 rows, or  2 rows and 4 columns?

Comment: Sorry, I totally screwed the table up. The table is fine (in my rendering). I'll edit to reflect.

Comment: Your code as posted works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/dpj3rq96/1/ . There must be something else going on. Please provide enough code to replicate the problem.

Comment: Do you have any white space characters that may be affecting the sort order, either before, after, on in the middle of the the first column data?

Comment: I will dig into this further and figure out what could be causing the discrepancy. Thank you, Jon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to disable initial sorting for jquery DataTables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964388/is-there-a-way-to-disable-initial-sorting-for-jquery-datatables)

Comment: @Rich perfect!!! Thank you. `"aaSorting": []` worked like a charm. We can close this. Or should I delete?

Comment: The updated option setting for version 1.10 and above is ["order"](https://datatables.net/reference/option/order)