# Preventing data table default sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to prevent by default sorting in data table.

Below is the code I am using.

```
$('#tableId').dataTable( {
    "bPaginate": true,
    "stateSave": true                       
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to disable initial sorting for jquery DataTables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964388/is-there-a-way-to-disable-initial-sorting-for-jquery-datatables)

Comment: i tried this but it did't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using this : [columns.orderable](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderable) ?

```
$('#tableId').dataTable( {
    "bPaginate": true,
    "stateSave": true,
    "columnDefs": [{ "orderable": false, "targets": '_all' }]                     
});
```

Comment: i tried your  **suggestion**  but issue remained same.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#tableId').dataTable( {
  "bPaginate": true,
  "columnDefs": [{ "orderable": false, "targets": '_all' }] 
});
```

Actually it save the state of previous one , after removing state save property its working fine.